# Alfresco failed to find new folder

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I'm using alfresco throw cmis.
On one of our environment, we have an issue.
We want to create a folder and put some docs in it.

This  works fines in all our env except one.

In this one, we can create the folder.
But when we do a search to find the folder, the folder isn't found.

After that i can find it with the share gui.

I have no error message in the share app.

Does any one have an idea on what could be the issue?

Comment: Are you using Alfresco with SOLR? SOLR isn't quite real-time, so it may take a second or two for newly created things to show up in search

Comment: that was the issue, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

When using Alfresco with SOLR, you need to be aware that the SOLR index isn't quite real-time. Close to real time, sure, but it's asynchronous so there's always a lag. (It's an eventually consistent index, not a fully realtime one)

There's a lot of information on the [Alfresco and SOLR Wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_And_SOLR), including the way you can query what the current lag is.

If the lag is very low (eg a lightly loaded system), you can find that SOLR will catch up almost instantly, and newly created items will show instantly in the search results. However, it's more normal to expect to have to wait a little bit, especially on more loaded systems.

If no new results are showing up even after several minutes, you'll want to follow the instructions on the wiki or the [SOLR Monitoring and Troubleshooting docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/solr-monitor-troubleshoot.html) to work out why and fix.